# Is there any way to update data sent ALONG WITH THE PARTIAL while rendering a hbs partial(nodejs,mogodb,express) without actually reloading a webpage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, handlebars.js

Is there any way to update data sent ALONG WITH THE PARTIAL while rendering a hbs partial(nodejs,mogodb,express) without actually reloading a webpage?

For instance I've a post route for comment, querying the database and rendering a view along with some json data fetched from database.
Now that i want to show any newly added comment without actually refreshing the page. I can do that with ajax but the only issue is the route sends the partial view and data along , how do i show that newly added data(comment) without re-rendering the page.

P.s. I'm a total beginner with this.

View file snippet:

```
      <!-- Comments Form -->
     {{#if user}}
      {{#if post.allowComments}}
      <div class="card my-4">
        <h5 class="card-header">Leave a Comment:</h5>
        <div class="card-body">
          <form action='/admin/comments' method='post'>
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea name='body' class="form-control" required rows="3"></textarea>
              <input type="hidden" name='id' value="{{post.id}}">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      {{else}} <h3>Comments are Not Allowed on this Post</h3><hr>
       {{/if}}
      {{else}} <h3>You need to <a href="/login">Log in </a>to Comment</h3><hr>
      {{/if}}
       
      <!-- Single Comment -->
      {{#each post.comments}}
      <div class="media mb-4">
        <img class="d-flex mr-3 rounded-circle" src="/uploads/profile.jpg" alt="" height="40" width="40">
        <div class="media-body">
          <h5 class="mt-0">{{user.username}}</h5>
          {{body}}
        </div>
      </div>
      {{/each}}
```

Route that renders the above view:

```
router.get('/post/:id',(req, res)=>{
  Post.findOne({_id:req.params.id})
  .populate({path: 'comments', populate: {path: 'user',models: 'users'}})
  .populate('user')
  .then((post)=>{
    Category.find({}).then((categories)=>{
      res.render('layouts/post',{post,categories})
    })
  })
})
```

So basically i want to update the {post, categories} sent along with the post view and show the newly added comments too on the front-end without re rendering the entire page again.

So far I'm able to add new comments but everytime I add a new comment, it shows with page refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a live page in a browser wants to get updates without refreshing the page, you have a few options for how to do it.

1. **Ajax call that returns HTML segment.**  You can create a route on the server expressly for updates that returns a portion of the page HTML (just the portion you wish to update).   Then, your page Javascript will issue that Ajax call, get the HTML and replace a portion of the HTML on your page with the newly retrieved HTML using DOM manipulations with your front-end Javascript.  On your server, you would not render an entire page, but would render only a portion of the page (the portion that your front-end wishes to replace).  If you organize your HBS partials appropriately, you can share the same partial between this Ajax call and the rendering of the whole page.
2. **Ajax call that returns JSON.**.  You create a route on the server expressly for updates that returns JSON data only.  It is then the front-end's responsibility to turn that JSON into HTML and insert it in the page.  You can use client-side HBS to render the JSON if you want.  This is basically the same structure as option #1 above - the only difference is where the data is changed into HTML.
3. **Use webSocket or socket.io connection to deliver data asynchronously rather than a polling Ajax call.**  Either of the above two options can replace the Ajax call with a webSocket or socket.io connection from the client to the server.  Then, the server is free to send the client updates (over that webSocket/socket.io connection) whenever it notices that something has changed that the client may wish to display.  This is more of a "push" model than a "polling Ajax" model.

Also, it is not clear from your question, but if your POST is coming from a form post where the browser is submitting the POST automatically, then the page will always be refreshed after that based on the response from the POST.  That's how automatic form posts work.  If you don't want the page to be refreshed, then you have to change the POST to be a Javascript submitted POST where your client-side Javascript receives the response from the POST and can then decide what it wants to do with the returned data and the browser will not automatically display or refresh anything.

Comment: Thanks much, your options 1 and 2 actually gave me new insights about how can i achieve what I'm trying .